# How to configure linter for VSCode with format C++20

Tags: visual-studio-code, c++20, linter

I'm using VS Code 1.78.2 with C/C++ extensions on Windows 10 and use MinGW64 for compiling so:

```
$> g++ --version
g++ (x86_64-win32-seh-rev1, Built by MinGW-Builds project) 13.1.0
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

I'm using <[format](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format)> and added **-std=c++20** to my compilation flags and my code is working fine.

But when I'm in the editor, it's keep showing me an error. It's probably my linter that I misconfigured but after some research on the internet and some tests i didn't find what is wrong

[image: Error Image]

**c_cpp_properties.json**

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win64",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}\\include\\**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.19041.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++20",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64",
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.makefile-tools"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

I don't know where to search now, my question is :
How to configure my C/C++ extension to get my linter properly works with the **format** header ?

Do you have met this problem ? do you have any advice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution but behind the answer there is logic.

While continuing my project, I encountered other header inclusion problems that were sometimes detected, sometimes not by the intellisense. A random behavior of my *C/C++ extension* on VS Code which was wasting a lot of my time..

As I said before, I was using *MinGW64* and my *C/C++ extension* uses its compiler for intellisense. But *MinGW* is an adaptation of the GNU tools which are designed to work on a Linux system with probably some specific headers for that.

However, Windows has its own standard compilation tools: **Microsoft Visual C++ (MSVC) with 'cl'** which have been designed in the same way to work easily with the latest versions of Windows and therefore **the headers of MSVC should work better than those of GNU for a Windows system**.

So I installed MSVC by following this tutorial: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc

Then I re-configured my *C/C++ extension* to use *MSVC* and magic, the intellisense works perfectly well, even with the header format